# Laravel. Get single column values of a table using Query Builder

Tags: laravel, controller

I have a table named "items" and an input for the where condition named "ref_code".

```
$items = DB::table('items')
             ->where('ref_code','=', $request->ref_code)
             ->get(['id', 'ref_code', 'name','price']);
```

But I can't seem to take the values of each column.

I checked wether the query builder worked or not by using:

```
return $items;
```

Fortunately, there's no problem.

But returning or getting a single value doesn't work with:

```
return $items->id
```

Is my syntax wrong? All of this are inside my controller.

EDIT: I tried

```
dd($items);
```

before returning and it showed me this:

```
  Collection {#325 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => {#322 ▶}
  ]
}
```

Comment: P.S: I used POST method to throw the ref_code input from the blade.

Comment: `$items` would be a collection, hence you would need to loop through `$items` to get its properties

Comment: make `dd($items)` and update question with the result

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks for updating your question with the result. Look at your debug result. it looks like

```
array:1 [▼
    0 => {#322 ▶}
  ]
```

That means your query returning a collection of arrays because of you're using `get()` method. so `get()` method always return a collection of an array.

For avoiding this problem you have to use `first()` method instead of `get()`. 
**Remember**: all the time you have to use first() method when you want to get a single row.

So your query should be  like :

```
$items = DB::table('items')
             ->select('id', 'ref_code', 'name', 'price')
             ->where('ref_code','=', $request->ref_code)
             ->first();
```

Or

```
$item = YourModelName::select('id', 'ref_code', 'name', 'price')
             ->where('ref_code','=', $request->ref_code)
             ->first();
```

**And finally get output as like** 
$item->id, $item->ref_code etc.

Hope it will help.

**References:** https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#retrieving-results

Comment: Thank you! This worked like magic like the other answer. Big help guys. :)

Comment: Select my provided solution as an answer. So it will be helpful for me as well.

Answer (score 2):

[`get()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#retrieving-models) would return a collection

```
$items = DB::table('items')
         ->where('ref_code','=', $request->ref_code)
         ->get(['id', 'ref_code', 'name','price']);
```

In the above case `$items` would be a collection, hence you need to loop through the collection to access the properties

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $item->price;
}
```

If you'd need to return a Model instance you could use the method [`first()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#retrieving-single-models) instead

```
$items = DB::table('items')
             ->select('id', 'ref_code', 'name', 'price')
             ->where('ref_code','=', $request->ref_code)
             ->first();
```

and access the properties as

```
$items->price;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using model

```
$result =  Model_name::where('ref_code','=', $request->ref_code)
                       ->first(['id', 'ref_code', 'name', 'price']);
```